# Alert Popup Problen

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with an alert function I am making. The alert is only supposed to go off when the user presses the back button. The problem is that the alert shows up when the users try to close the page too. Any way to fix this? Here is the code. I make this work by setting the Boolean to true on any link clicked, which shuts off the alert.

EDIT: For anyone who caught it, yeah a quotation mark was missing. That was just me editing the code within here and accidentally deleting a quotation mark. It isn't actually a problem and I fixed it within the code here.

```
<script>
 var okayToLeave = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   if (!okayToLeave) {
   return "By going back, you risk submitting your order twice."
   }
}

function OkayToLeave() {
    okayToLeave = true;
}
```

Comment: This is a mega faq. Fix your form submission instead

Comment: This question has been asked more than 100000 times on various fora including this (just search this site for onbeforeunload). Fix your backend so it can handle the issue instead of trying to hack your front end to patch the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a missing "
in the following line:

`return "By going back, you risk submitting your order twice."`

edit:

your `OkayToLeave` method should define the `onbeforeunload`.

so instead of setting a value to true you should consider just adding that event.

edit2:

here is a code example:

```
function NotOkayToLeave() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "By going back, you risk submitting your order twice.";
    };
};

function OkayToLeave() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};
```

Comment: i agree that the grammar is off, but i think the other issue is that he/she needs a way to set okayToLeave when no links have been clicked, right?

Comment: sorry, that was just an edit issue when I put the code in. There are no problems there. Matt is on the right track.

Comment: Yeah, Matt, that is the problem. I have it working for the back button, but when I try to close the window, the alert comes up, when it shouldn't be. It should only be happening for the back button.

Comment: but that doesn't solve the problem. Just replaces code with other code. I need to know how to remove the alert for when the user tries to close the window. It doesn't matter what I use to make it not show the alert, as long as it is not there.

Comment: beliefe it or not. its impossible to detect if someone clicked the back button or closed the window. it basicly is the same for `window.onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 1):

Am not aware of any way of determining whether an unload is caused by close or back action simply by the event. However, as an alternative solution, you can use the hash tag to work as a buffer (this assumes you cannot redirect to another page entirely, which would be the preferred solution (besides setting a session value to prevent double-submitting)).

When they get to the page, change the hash tag with javascript. Then, detect when the hash changes back (the back button) and throw the alert and add back the hash.

The jquery hashChange plugin is one way of detecting the change.

https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange

Comment: how can I redirect to another page entirely? Can you show me a good link on how to do this?